# Different Matrix Multiplication Computation Gives Output Matrices of Different Shapes

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

[Click Here For Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2qcKq.png)

Are these output matrices the same even though they are of different shapes (2x1) vs (1x1)?

Although these output matrices are of different shapes, they contain the same values -1 and 3.

Comment: They are different if you want to treat them as different.  They are the same if you want to treat them as the same.  Math is very fluid about things like that.  For instance, you should be well used to the idea that we can talk about $1+1=2$ without clarifying what type of object "$1$" is... whether it was the natural number $1$, the integer $1$, the real number $1$, the complex number $1$, or so on... each of which are formally different objects with different rules and formal representations, yet we swap freely between the objects depending on context and circumstances.

Comment: By the fact that you used an "equals" sign for your "#2" equality, it implies to me that you should be treating them as the same.  If you wanted to treat the final objects as different then your "#2" equality was unjustified and incorrect.

Comment: @JMoravitz Okay, thank you.